# paint() vs paintEvent() in Qt

Tags: qt, paint, qgraphicsitem, paintevent

I have two questions.

1. What is the difference between `paint()` of `QGraphicsItem` and `paintEvent()` of `QWidget` APIs?
2. I am developing a timer kinda GUI, so I am updating the screen every 100ms with `paint()` API on embedded linux board. It consumes almost all of the CPU. Any idea how to prevent this?

Or is there any other method to do this simple graphics?

3. Also I have multiple `QGraphicsScene` each with its own `QGraphicsView` in a grid layout. How to update the individual view from the MainWindow.

Below is the code how I currently do this:

```
/****SCENE 1*****/
    scene_1 = new QGraphicsScene();
    scene_1->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::black);
    ui->gv_1->setScene(scene_1);
    ui->gv_1->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    circle = scene_1->addEllipse(50, 80, 150, 150, outlinePen, darkGreyBrush);
    textSlotNo = scene_1->addText("1", QFont("Arial", 30) );
    textSlotNo->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::gray);
    textSlotNo->setPos(0,50);

    MyItem *item_1 = new MyItem(1);
    scene_1->addItem(item_1);
    item_1->timer = new QTimer();
    connect(item_1->timer, SIGNAL(timeout()),scene_1, SLOT(update()));
    item_1->timer->start(100);

/****SCENE 2*****/
......
```

**Hardware: TI-AM3354**

Comment: Also add the code that updates the items every 100ms. Having a timer per item is certainly not efficient, and it looks like you repaint everything even if nothing changed. Try to simply update the items if their properties change, and don't call update() manually at all.

Comment: I do update the scene every 100ms. I draw an arc with different start position, thereby making it as if it is rotating. And I also update time using drawText() inside the scene. Is there any other way without using QTimer on every scene?

Comment: I just used one timer and the CPU was consumed fully by that one timer alone.

Comment: How many scenes do you have?

Comment: I got 10 scenes to update. Just testing with one for now.

Comment: In the case of rotation, try to rotate the item using http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setRotation instead of repainting it every frame. Using OpenGL might also help.

Comment: OpenGL would be an overhead for this. Anyways, now I need to update it only every minute so it won't be an issue. And I have a memory related question. In the above code, I create scenes and `MyItem` objects using `new`, so is it ok to leave those without deleting? Since this is the only application running in the system...Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

1. `paintEvent()` is a generic event handler and is called by Qt to paint a widget, usually the whole widget, but that sometimes can be optimized by respecting QPaintEvent's region and rect properties.
2. `paint()` is called on individual QGraphicsItems by a QGraphicsView when painting the QGraphicsScene. It usually won't be called on all items, QGraphicsView does various checks before painting the item, e.g. ensuring that the item is in the viewport and not hidden by other items, etc.

From the code you posted, I see two optimizations: First, don't run a QTimer individually for each item, but one timer for the whole scene. Right now your code triggers up to N repaints every 100 ms, instead of a single one. Also, update the properties of your items and let them call [QGraphicsItem::update()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#update) *on themselves* if the property actually changed, instead of updating the whole scene unconditionally.

Comment: Call QGraphicsItem::update() http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#update when the item actually changed and only then

Comment: I change the visuals of the item i.e call `update()` on the slot of `QTimer` every 1 minute now. And for the single timer idea, should I register an event for each item and use it in timerEvent()? Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: I am updating each view in a separate slot like this `connect(item_1->timer, SIGNAL(timeout()),this, SLOT(updateUI_1()));` and inside `updateUI_1()` I call `scene_1->update()` Can you please let me know is this the correct way?

Comment: You shouldn't have to call update() on the scene at all, just update the item properties and let them call update() internally if the property actually changed